# Computer-native files deleted from discarding changes in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, delete-file, source-control-explorer

In a frazzled state I am writing this: in an attempt to make my javascript code in VS Code to run, I did something which might be completely unrelated to the issue (by discarding all untracked changes in source control), after which many of my files in the folders under document & all files in desktop disappeared. Is there a way to retrieve all these materials? I am in deep regret and have to learn from this mistake which might cause irreversible deletion.

Unfortunately the trash did not include anything. Even worse, these stuff may not have a backup.

Comment: Yes, "untracked files" means everything not under version control, and deleting them is irreversible. (Although usually they *should* have been moved to trash - there might be settings in the OS or VS Code to control this). If you have lost important files that you'll need to recover, stop using the computer (disk) immediately and try a hard disk file recovery tool from a different computer. Apart from that, looks like you learned a lesson wrt backups and not opening your entire desktop folder in vscode